# Проблема с концом ввода F3

Tags: c#, строки

Задача состоит в следующем. **Вводится текст , конец ввода F3, Расставить слова по убыванию количества букв.**
По идее вроде бы код правильно написал , но не хочет работать.
Программа не хочет заканчиваться на F3.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace labaa2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string s;
            Console.WriteLine("vvod texta: ");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (var word in s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))
                Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
        static void EnterWhileNotF3(StringBuilder text)//ввод текста до F3
        {
            var input = Console.ReadKey();
            while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.F3)
            {
                text.Append(input.KeyChar);
                input = Console.ReadKey();
            }
            
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: А где в вашем коде хоть один вызов метода `EnterWhileNotF3`?

Comment: не знаю даже... а как должен был сделать ?-@EvgeniyZ

Comment: Скажите, вот вы допустим купили в магазине технику новую, к примеру, обогреватель, принесли домой, но он вас не греет, вы в ярости несете его в магазин и там говорят, а вы в розетку воткнуть не пробовали? А кнопку включения нажимали? Вот тут сейчас аналогичная ситуация, у вас есть написанный метод, но вы его не вызываете, не используете и просите людей о помощи, не подумав самостоятельно в чем проблема, так может подумайте, вызовите этот метод и посмотрите на результат?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ хорошо , попробую

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нет расстановки по убыванию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209298/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)